# Dynamically modifying an IEnumerable property via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, types, propertyinfo, dynamictype

I have a variety of classes that have various properties that implement `IEnumerable` (eg `IEnumerable<string>`, `IEnumerable<bool>`, `IEnumerable<enum>`, etc). I'm trying to write some code to filter down the values of theses properties (eg if the value is `{ "one", "two", "three" }` I might want to filter where `.Contains("t")`).

Here's the essence of what I've got:

```
class MyObject
{
    public IEnumerable<string> stringProp { get; set; } = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    public IEnumerable<bool> boolProp { get; set; } = new[] { true, false, true };
    public IEnumerable<int> intProp { get; set; } = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(MyObject).GetProperties())
    {               
        prop.SetValue(obj, (prop.GetValue(obj) as IEnumerable<dynamic>).Where(val => val != null));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to set the value back to the object (`property.SetValue`) an error is thrown because the new value is an `IEnumerable<object>`.

```
Object of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'
```

I've tried `Convert.ChangeType` but that does not work because `IEnumerable` does not implement `IConvertible`.

How might I accomplish this? Why does the LINQ `Where` query change the `IEnumerable<dynamic>` into `IEnumerable<object>`?

Comment: Can you please add the error and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Also it is not `Where` which transforms your type, but [compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8AGAAn2JQG4L8BmOwmgYRoG8Kaguu3woaAWQAUASj4ChC+qwA8GAJ4A7AIYBbAJZgAfDQQ0AvDQ0BXADY3m5BQF8KToA===)

Comment: IEnumerable<dynamic> IS IEnumerable<object> with less compile-time checks. You either have to switch to a TItemType or use the non-generic IEnumerable implementation. Either way, you might have to rethink the code. Also, it's not clear to me what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: 99 times out of 100, the use of `dynamic` is creating 2 more problems for every problem it solves.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did I understand correctly? Are you looking for something like this?

```
var obj = new MyObject();

foreach (var prop in typeof(MyObject).GetProperties())
{
    //assumming all things are IEnumerable<something>
    var type = prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

    //We can't "instantiate" something as ephemeral as an IEnumerable,
    //so we need something more concrete like a List
    //There might be other ways to filter - this seemed to be the easiest
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var instance = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    
    var currentEnum = (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(obj);
    foreach (var item in currentEnum)
    {
         if (item != default) // != null would be silly for booleans and ints
         {
             instance.Add(item);
         }
    }

    prop.SetValue(obj, instance);
}
```

Summary: Generics and the dynamic keyword don't usually mix this way - having a dynamic generic argument makes no sense. Think of dynamic as something that actually means "object" but also lets you write whatever you like against it. And of course, IEnumerable<object> is probably better off as IEnumerable. And for generics with multiple parameters, you're better off with object or even better a specific class.

Comment: Ah, yes! That works! I didn't know about `MakeGenericType` or `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Depending on what you actually want to do in your code, you might want to also look into Expressions and Funcs. Perhaps you could do this without all this nasty Reflection :)